# Converting an integer to a double inside switch case

Tags: c#, switch-statement, type-conversion

This program is for a payroll but i haven't got far yet

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("What is your hourly rate\n1=6.53\n2=7.48\n3=8.89");
int hourlyRate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("How many hours do you work?\n1=35\n2=38\n43");
int noOfHour = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("What is you National Insurance no.?\n1=JLS302\n2=KM8215\nPQ7316");
int niNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

switch (hourlyRate)
{
    case 1: hourlyRate == 6.53;
}
```

I'm not sure how exactly to convert hourlyRate which has the value of an integer to 6.43 which is a decimal

Comment: answere below. just introduce a new variable for the actual rate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to declare a variable as double to hold the actual rate.

Since you are using hourlyRate to hold the "selection" you'll probably need another variable to hold the actual rate: like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("What is your name");
string name = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("What is your hourly rate\n1=6.53\n2=7.48\n3=8.89");
int hourlyRate = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("How many hours do you work?\n1=35\n2=38\n43");
int noOfHour = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Console.WriteLine("What is you National Insurance no.?\n1=JLS302\n2=KM8215\nPQ7316");
int niNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

//ADDED this here:
double rate = 0.00;
switch (hourlyRate)
{
    case 1: {
        rate = 6.53;
        break;
    }
    case 2: {
        rate = 7.48;

        break;
    }
    case 3: {
        rate = 8.89;
        break;
    }       

}
Console.WriteLine("This is the rate: " + rate);
```

Comment: This is what i had originally but my teacher wants us use '1=6.53' etc for validation

Comment: just updated the code. I see what you are saying now, you just need another variable to hold the actual rate. Keep what you add but look at the comment I added above //ADDED this here:

Comment: thank you, i wouldn't have chosen this method either but my teacher wants us to practice other structures. Btw this was my first post cheers ;P

Comment: you could also havealso initialized rate to be the following 
`double rate = 0d;`

Answer (score 0):

if I understand OP correctly hourly rates has 3 options n1,n2,n3
and so :

```
double hourlyRate = 8.89;
var hourlyRateType = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
if (hourlyRateType == "1")
{
     hourlyRate  = 6.53;
}
else if (hourlyRateType == "2")
{
     hourlyRate  = 7.48;
}
```

same pattern should be done for National Insurance no

and an easier way is like this :

```
var rateMapping= new Dictionary<string,double>() {{"1",6.53}, {"2",7.48}...}

var hourlyRate = rateMapping[Console.ReadLine().ToLower()];
```

Answer (score -1):

Why dont you just convert the value to int like below:

```
switch (hourlyRate)
{
    case 1: hourlyRate == (int)6.53;
}
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: That would truncate the value to 6.

Comment: his hourlyrate is already converted to int. So, instead of doing (int) maybe do Convert.ToInt32(6.53) ?